# Is my sample representative?

Tags: sample-size, sample, small-sample

I hnave a computer process that does some classifications.

After that I choose 10% of that data and manually classified those analyzed records into correct and incorrect.

I found out that around 10% of the sample was classified in my computer process with an error.

First, is my sample representative? Can I infer that 1% of the data has an error (like the sample)?

Does this achieve 95% confidence for the work the computer process has done?

As you might have guessed, I know only the basics.

Thanks

Comment: Nobody can help me with figuring out the math behind this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the record: this is what I was looking for:

http://www.sut.ac.th/im/data/read6.pdf

In the article, the author describes how to calculate the sample size. Based on the reading and how my sample is generated (simple random), I've decided to use the Yamane's formula, which is pretty simple:

n = N / 1 + N * e^2

Where:

n is the sample size (what you're trying to get)
N is the population size
e is the level of precision you want to achieve (+-5%)

So:

n = 2000 / 1 + 2000 * 0.5^2

Which is: 333